# What is the meaning of "if you would on your little diagram" in the following context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, slang

What is the meaning of "if you would on your little diagram" in the following context?

> if you would on your little diagram here, I'd like you to go ahead and actually sketch out the parts of this you know, like what is the cue? What is this emotion that arises?

Answer (score 2):

The words in the sentence are merely arranged in a way that might make it a little confusing to some. The same sentence could be rewritten as, "*On your little diagram here, I'd like you to go ahead and actually sketch out **if you would**, the parts of this you know, like what is the cue? What is this emotion that arises?*" and it would mean exactly the same thing. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much . It's so clear now 

Comment: My pleasure really

Comment: And “if you would” is short for “if you would be so kind as to...”